# How to create an attribute-directive in Angular 2 and bind it to a property?

Tags: angular

I want to create a custom attribute-directive and bind this to a property. I plan to retrieve this attribute and get the value later on.

I created a Directive:

```
@Directive({ 
    selector: '[data-url]' 
})

export class DocumentURL{
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) { }
}
```

this is the component that uses the directive:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'some.component.html',
    directives: [DocumentURL]
})
```

this is my some.component.html:

```
<div class="col-xs-6" [data-url]='docUrl' (mouseleave)='onMouseLeave($event)'>
```

However, it is throwing an error saying that:
Can't bind to 'data-url' since it isn't a known native property

Can someone help please? thanks.

Comment: which Angular version you are using?

Comment: Angular 2 is the version I am using

Comment: What Angular2 version?

Comment: You have to put a directive inside declaration of NgModule then

Comment: 2.0.0-beta.15 version

Comment: What is your purpose of doing it?

Comment: i have a popup window on mouse event and the data is coming from that attribute.

Comment: So ultimately you want to grab that attribute value right? If so ,what if I show you other way with directive only?

Comment: put 

    @Input('data-url') dataUrl: string;

in your directive and use dataUrl in ngOnInit

Comment: hi Kit, what's the value to initialize dataUrl in ngOnInit?

Comment: micronyks: yes, that is right. can you show me the other way please?

Comment: docUrl is it a static value?

Comment: nope it is a dynamic value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add an `@Input` property in your directive.

```
@Directive({ 
    selector: '[data-url]' 
})
export class DocumentURL{

    @Input('data-url')
    dataUrl:string;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) { }
}
```

See [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AMpcDgyNyBawvNPN9QUG?p=preview).

Comment: i did this one but still it's not being recognized.

Comment: It's weird, I create a plunkr and it works for me :/

Comment: thanks Noemi. It worked for me now as well. However, when i checked the data using f12, i didn't see any data. Any reason why? I may have missed something.

Comment: You just saved my life <3